# SWIFTUI - custom color set

Tags: swiftui

I'm using this Initialiser to style my navigationBarTitle. It works fine but in darkmode it doesnt look right. Is there a way to change the colors below to use color sets so it looks fine in darkmode?

```
   // Custom Header Initialiser.

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white

        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,

            .font : UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 24)!]

        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            .font : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 18)!]
    }

    //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom color set in Assets catalog (eg. named MyColor) and assign your variants for needed appearances, eg. as below

[image: demo]

Assing your custom color as below

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "MyColor")
```

Comment: Thank you Asperi, the background color works but can't figure out the foreground color? UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,